# Preventing automatic line break in xml on Atom editor?

Tags: atom-editor

Hello everyone.

I am new to Atom and using atom to see xml files. (I didn't setup any additional packages yet. Version 1.19.4)

One of my xml files consist of many attributes. For example..

```
<book id="test_xml">
  <class name="First_row" attrib_01="Grape" attrib_02="Apple" attrib_03="banana" attrib_04="Water melon" attrib_05="Orange" ... (and so on )
</book>
```

Every  has 50 attributes at least.

First time I opened this xml file in atom editor, It shows every class in single line. (This is what I want.) But when I edit attribute value ("Melon" to "Apple"), atom editor breaks the line suddenly and showed one line to multi line like belows.

```
<book id="Fruit">
<class name="First_row" attrib_01="Grape" attrib_02="Apple"
attrib_03="banana" attrib_04="Water melon"
attrib_05="Orange" ... (and so on )
</book>
```

Without changing xml format, how to prevent split the single line  to multi line?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce. Are you sure it's actually breaking as opposed to soft-wrapping? Way to tell is if there's a line number or not on "both" of the broken lines.

Comment: Oh, Although It shows on multiple line. Line number is same. For example, line number is 160 and there's a dot(.) showed until next <class> comes. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: No problem. Always remember too that you can toggle soft-wrap in the command palette (ctrl-shift-p or cmd-shift-p on a mac) and type "soft": it should be the first hit.